# Getting facebook event images

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

Is there a way to retrieve posted images in facebook events?
https://graph.facebook.com/event_id/cover gives only the cover of that event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/photos/

> Photos published to the event

All the possible data and all the possible edges can be found in the API reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event

Comment: Idk, it used to give 50x50 images before. Now it's ok but it's still a mystery for me.